# How to match names in two sheets?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am using excel to keep track of attendance but i find this very difficult. Is there a way/formula for this?

Problem.
Sheet 1 column A1-30 will show the list of people for day 1. Contains list of names say (Last name, First name ONLY) 
Sheet 2 column J1-3000 also contains a list of names but with middle names in it (Last Name, First Name Middle Name)

How can i match two sheets to create a third sheet that will show who attended Day 1?

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Do you need help with the matching, or dealing with the middle name?

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I need to deal with the middle names, I GUESS(?) I cannot find a way to match names on both sheets with sheet 2 having a long list(edited my question). The third sheet should compare sheet 1 and sheet 2 and will only show names of people in sheet 1 and say Error if they're not.

Answer (score 1):

use `vlookup` function to match values
Read this: http://chandoo.org/wp/2012/03/30/comprehensive-guide-excel-vlookup/

use the following formula to get rid of the middle name (which is in the following expected format: *(Lname,Fname,Mname)*

```
=TRIM(LEFT(A1,(FIND(",",A1,1)-1)))&", "&TRIM(LEFT(MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+1,100),FIND(",",MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+1,100))-1))
```

***please note, it adds the space in between fname and lastname `John,Smith,Midname` -> `John, Smith`*

or, as @Craig Q suggested, use `=LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1,FIND(",",A1)+1)-1`

Therefore.

- Step1: Create a new column on Sheet2 (the sheet which lists the middlenames)
- Step2: Use the formula to get rid of the middle names for all rows
- Step3: Manually test couple of items in the new column on the Sheet2 and Sheet1 and make sure that they match by using this formula `=A1=Sheet2!A1` (please manually find the same records on both sheets when you test your entries!!!!!)
- Step4: When you sure that entries on both sheets match (Formula in #3 must return `TRUE`)
- Step5: Use vlookup  using values from Step2 within records on Sheet1

Comment: To get rid of the middle name, why not just find the second comma and truncate there? `=LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1,FIND(",",A1)+1)-1)`

Comment: @CraigW, I am not sure; if it will provide a match, then yes; you 100% correct. I am not sure how the first sheet names are formatted(do they have spaces or not). User-maintained data always is a mess and I prefer to split it to the source and rebuild again to guarantee a match...

Comment: Sheet 1 names are formatted this way(Last Name, First Name)         Sheet 2 (Last Names, First Name Middle Name) first name and middle names separated by a space.

Comment: @Andrew THANK YOU! Appreciate all the help! :)